# Selected feature is not feature type

Tags: openlayers, features

I have multiple features that I display, and on click a popup appears, with a button to store it to favorites (with intention of show only favorites afterwards)

The thing is, when I click the button, I retrieve the selected feature through the select interaction, but the feature that retrieves is not a feature type, is an object like this:

```
featureAtClick Object { $a: Object, ta: Object, qa: Object, f: 1, ko: 568, I: Object, a: undefined, : "geometry", g: null, l: undefined, 2 more… }
```

Instead of:

```
Object { type: "Feature", geometry: Object, properties: Object }
```

The properties of my feature are all inside of the I key from the first object, but for a reason I can not access to it.

I tried this:

```
Object.keys(selected).forEach(function (prop){console.log(selected[prop])})
console.log('selected',selected['I'])
```

But it returns only empty objects.

How do I convert it to a feature type, so I can add it to a featurecollection and display it later?

**EDIT**

As requested I add the click event code. This is the click on the feature:

```
favorites = { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [] }
                map.on('click', function (evt) {               
                    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
                    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
                        if (feature) {
                            console.log('favorites', favorites)
                            console.log('featureatclick',feature)
                            if (favorites.features.indexOf(feature) === -1) {
                                $('#fav-select').text('☆')
                            } else {
                                $('#fav-select').text('★')
                            }
    /// So the idea is that if the feature is on the favorite list, display either one text or another
                            $('#popup-content').html('<p><span>Name</span>: ' + feature.get('name') + '</p>');
                            $('#popup-content').append('<p><span>Address</span>: ' + feature.get('address') + '</p>');
                            if (feature.get('rank') != undefined) {
                                $('#popup-content').append('<p><span>Rank</span>: ' + feature.get('rank') + '</p>');
                                $('#popup-content').append('<p><span>Reviews</span>: ' + feature.get('reviews') + '</p>');
                            }
                            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
                            map.addOverlay(overlay)


                        }
                    });
                });
```

And this the click on the favorites button:

```
                $('#fav-select').on('click', function (t) {

                var selected = selectInteraction.getFeatures()
                Object.keys(selected).forEach(function (prop){console.log(selected[prop])})
                console.log('selected',selected['I'])
/// Here I retrieve the feature that is selected again, and check if it is on the list to either remove it or add it
                if (favorites.features.indexOf(selected) === -1) {
                    console.log('fav')
                    favorites.features.push(selected)
                     $('#fav-select').text('★')
                     console.log('favoritesfavselect', favorites)
                } else {
                    console.log('unfav')
                    $('#fav-select').text('☆')
                    favorites.features.splice(favorites.features.indexOf(selected), 1)
                    console.log('favoritesfavselect', favorites)
                }

                console.log('selected', selected)
                console.log()

            })
```

Comment: Can you please add to your post how you handle the click event?

Comment: Sure, I just updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an object like this:

```
Object { type: "Feature", geometry: Object, properties: Object }
```

Just use:

```
new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeature(yourFeature);
```

If you want to access the properties use this:

```
yourFeature.getProperties();
```

To create a new collection with selected features you can also use:

```
var featureCollection = new ol.Collection();
// add feature
featureCollection.push(yourFeature);
```

Comment: If I try your appoach (.writeFeature) I get this error: 

`TypeError: a.U is not a function`

And getProperties returns this: 

`Object [ <1 empty slot> ]`

Comment: Please try to define your variable `selected` as: `var selected = selectInteraction.getFeatures().item(0)`. Currently your selected variable is not a `ol.Feature` but a `ol.Collection`

Comment: I can't press +1 to your answer yet, but that did the trick, thank you so much! The object is returned as an string, but with JSON.parse I get it as an object. Although now `favorites.features.indexOf(selected)` does not recognize the same object in the array.. I'm gonna work on it, thanks again

Comment: If you want to avoid the same feature to be added multiple times I suggest to use the `unique`option of `ol.Collection` (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Collection.html).

Comment: I did not manage to make the collection work, at the end I continued using the feature collection with the strings, and I just parse it at the moment of creating the layers. All works as intended now! Thanks